# Jquery Dialog close icon missing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

When I open the JQuery dialog, the close button icon is missing.
I have searched on Google and Stack Overflow and most people are saying that `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css` need to be included, but I have already included these `.css` and `.js` files. Yet for some reason the close icon is still missing.

[image]

Comment: did you check in images inside css folder that the icon is there?

Comment: In case the icon is there in the folder then check in chrome developer console whether you are getting a 404 for the image. Most possible case would be the relative path specified for the image is wrong.

Comment: recheck css image URL path and image path. also must be check image is existing ?

Comment: Yes,browser console is clean.

Comment: make a fiddle to show ur issue.

Comment: Check in runtime using your browsers Developer dialog if the images are _actually_ loaded

Comment: okay,I got my Solution. now it is working fine

Comment: Looks like it is a z-index issue. Have you tried altering default jQuery-dialog css style and changing z-index for different elements of close icon container?